# Excel autofill dates but not totally sequentially

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, increment, autofill

I'm trying to create a simple excel spreadsheet which tracks some things 3 times per day (morning, noon, and night). The table should look like this:

| Date | Time of Day | Thing 1 | Thing 2 | Thing 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/06/2023 | Morning | x | y | z |
| 26/06/2023 | Noon | x | y | z |
| 26/06/2023 | Night | x | y | z |
| 27/06/2023 | Morning | x | y | z |
| 27/06/2023 | Noon | x | y | z |
| 27/06/2023 | Night | x | y | z |
| 28/06/2023 | Morning | x | y | z |
| 28/06/2023 | Noon | x | y | z |
| 28/06/2023 | Night | x | y | z |

Thought this would be simple but can't get Excel to autofill in that way with dates (3 x same, and then increment).

Maybe there's a simple formula I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula Method:

In Cell A1 Enter starting Date

In Cell B1 `="Morning"`

In Cell B2 `=IF(B1="Morning","Noon",IF(B1="Noon","Night",IF(B1="Night","Morning","Morning")))`

In Cell A2 `=IF(B2="Morning",A1+1,A1)`

Drag to autofill the formulas down.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like this solution, simple to understand when I look back on it in future, and does the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Create Table Data

- The date column needs to be formatted manually.

[image]

- Possibly (probably) replace the inputs with cell references.
  For `Events` and `Things` use one cell per value.

```
=LET(FirstDate,DATEVALUE("26-6-2023"),dDays,5,
    Events,VSTACK("Morning","Noon","Night"),
    Things,HSTACK("x","y","z"),
    ec,TOCOL(Events),tr,TOROW(Things),
    eRows,ROWS(ec),totRows,eRows*dDays,tCols,COLUMNS(tr),
    d,FirstDate+INT(SEQUENCE(totRows,,0)/eRows),
    e,INDEX(ec,MOD(SEQUENCE(totRows,,0),eRows)+1),
    t,INDEX(tr,SEQUENCE(totRows,,1,0),SEQUENCE(,tCols)),
HSTACK(d,e,t))
```

- If you want to keep the values hardcoded, this could be a better approach:

```
=LET(FirstDate,DATEVALUE("26-6-2023"),dDays,5,
    Events,"Morning,Noon,Night",Things,"x,y,z",
    ec,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(Events,",")),tr,TOROW(TEXTSPLIT(Things,",")),
    eRows,ROWS(ec),totRows,eRows*dDays,tCols,COLUMNS(tr),
    d,FirstDate+INT(SEQUENCE(totRows,,0)/eRows),
    e,INDEX(ec,MOD(SEQUENCE(totRows,,0),eRows)+1),
    t,INDEX(tr,SEQUENCE(totRows,,1,0),SEQUENCE(,tCols)),
HSTACK(d,e,t))
```

Answer (score 1):

So like this:

```
IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,"="&B1)=3,B1+1,B1)
```

[image]

Then you can do this for Morning Noon and night:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:B4,"="&B4)=1,"Morning",IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:B4,"="&B4)=2,"Noon",IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:B4,"="&B4)=3,"Night","Error")))
```

[image]

But a simple vlookup() is easier:

[image]

Comment: Wow, there's quite some different approaches. All very creative.

Answer (score 1):

```
=MAKEARRAY(B2*3,5,
    LAMBDA(r,c,
CHOOSE(IF(c>3,3,c),
       INT(B1+(r-1)/3),
       CHOOSE(MOD(r-1,3)+1,"morning","noon","night"),
       CHOOSE(c-2,"x","y","z"))))
```

Where: `B1` is the start date
and `B2` is the number of different days to list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B5`

```
=LET(
      _nOfDays,E3,
      _timeOfDay,{"Morning","Noon","Night"},
      _todCols,COLUMNS(_timeOfDay),
      _rowsNeeded,_nOfDays*_todCols,
      _firstDate,DATE(D3,B3,C3),
      _dateIncrement,_firstDate+INT(SEQUENCE(_rowsNeeded,,0,1/_todCols)),
      _timeOfDayfill,INDEX(_timeOfDay,MOD(SEQUENCE(_rowsNeeded,,0),_todCols)+1),
      _things,{"x","y","z"},
      _header,HSTACK("Date","Time Of Day","Things"&SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_things))),
       IFERROR(VSTACK(_header,
        HSTACK(_dateIncrement,_timeOfDayfill,IFNA(_things,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_timeOfDayfill))))),
       "Please enter the Month,Day,Year and #ofDays in respective cells"))
```

---

Bit simpler approach without <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
        a,H1,
        b,I1,
        c,SEQUENCE(b*3,,0),
        d,INT(a+c/3),
        e,INDEX({"Morning","Noon","Night"},MOD(c,3)+1),
        f,IFNA({"x","y","z"},SEQUENCE(b*3)),
        HSTACK(d,e,f))
```

---

OR, inplace of <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> use <kbd>SWITCH( )</kbd>

```
=LET(
        a,H1,
        b,I1,
        c,SEQUENCE(b*3,,0),
        d,INT(a+c/3),
        e,SWITCH(MOD(c,3)+1,1,"Morning",2,"Noon","Night"),
        f,IFNA({"x","y","z"},SEQUENCE(b*3)),
        HSTACK(d,e,f))
```

---